# Размещение двух таблиц в одну линию Boostrap

Tags: bootstrap, table

Собственно, небольшой вопрос: таблицы в boostrap растягиваются на всю ширину страницы, есть две небольших таблицы, их необходимо разместить в одну линию, как решить эту проблему?

Comment: А вы сами пробовали?

Comment: Естественно. Почему и пишу про то, что таблицы bootstrap растягиваются на всю ширину родительского элемента, в моем случае panel. Вторая таблица размещается ниже. Как в HTML float:left, естественно не работает.

Comment: Так и выложите свои попытки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В bootstrap есть классы row и col. Попробуйте сделать, что-то вроде этого:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col">Вставляем сюда таблицу 1</div>
<div class="col">Вставляем сюда таблицу 2</div>
</div>
```

Тогда таблицы будут внутри колонок. 
Почитайте также [документацию](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/).

Comment: Спасибо. Да, я таким способом пробовал, первая таблица внутри col-md-9 padding-right:0px, вторая - col-md-3 padding-left:0px. padding для того, что бы визуально объединить таблицы. Но при уменьшении разрешения вторая таблица сползает вниз, что естественно всё портит.

Comment: Вы дали решение, а лучше когда автор выложит свои попытки.